# How to create a corrupt .bak file for testing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know it's kind of an odd question, but is it possible to deliberately make a .bak file for an MS SQL Server database corrupt for testing purposes ?  I'd like to make it corrupt so I can attempt restore through troubleshooting and to improve my troubleshooting skills of database recovery.

Cheers !

Comment: I would try: Open an existing file, truncate towards the middle, close.

Comment: Brent Ozar had a recent [video](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/corrupt-database-purpose-video/) on this

Comment: I guess by simply appending some random data to the file: `copy /b some_document.docx + your_backup.bak corrupted_backup.bak`

Comment: Thank you guys, much appreciated, will look into doing this :)

Comment: Paul Randal has a nice [blog series](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/dbcc-writepage/) on how to use `DBCC WRITEPAGE` to corrupt a database (for practice purposes, of course). This is used to corrupt an attached database, not a backup file, but that's still interesting.

Comment: You could probably just open it in note pad and save it.

Comment: Use a hex editor and randomly changing some bytes in the file?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CheckDB/88963/

Comment: A variation on the notepad suggestions. It might work if you just add a string at the beginning or end of the file. If you save that, it will be corrupt. And if you like to repair it, you know exactly which string should be removed again.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that even if you select any test/word document file and rename it as .bak, SQL would recognize it as corrupt!

Answer (score 0):

you can corrupt the .bak file simply opening it with a text editor and changing some arts, but you will not able to restore this file.
An alternative can be to use the unix dd command (you can find the windows executable).

Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks for the answer Giova, but I need to also be able to restore it. The point is to try to fix it after it got corrupted or to at least recover some of the data.

Comment: I think that you will not receive replies about repair a corrupted backup file. There are commercial tools doing it and, I think, a small number of people able to do it. THey will not share this secret skill with us. In any case, in to the real world, in case of database lost and corrupted backup you'd contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want to make it corrupt to a stage where I can restore it, not to just look at it :). You said with your solution, there's no restore possibility. I want something similar to what T.I posted above in a comment "Brent Ozar had a recent video on this"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backup and then edit its content. This will make your backup file corrupted. I believe that RedGate has very great scripts for working with files which you can read more about it here:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Here is a sample:

```
create database MyDb
go
Backup database MyDb to disk='C:\MyDb\Mydb.bak'
go

declare @currentContent nvarchar(max)
set @currentContent = (Select dbo.[ufsReadfileAsString]('c:\MyDb','MyDb.bak'))
set @currentContent = @currentContent +'some text'
execute spWriteStringToFile @currentContent, 'c:\MyDb','MyDb_Corrupted.bak'
go
```

Now `MyDb_Corrupted.bak` is the corrupted file and the `MyDb.bak` is the healthy backup file. Note that in order to execute this script you should enable the `Ole Automation Procedure` using the following script:

```
 exec sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures','1'
 reconfigure
```